# How to use ifelse and paste functions

Tags: r, if-statement

I am learning the use of the *ifelse* function from Zuur et al (2009) A Beginners guide to R. In one exercise, there is a data frame called Owls which contains data about about 27 nests and two night of observations.

```
structure(list(Nest = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "AutavauxTV", class = "factor"), 
    FoodTreatment = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Deprived", 
    "Satiated"), class = "factor"), SexParent = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Male", class = "factor"), ArrivalTime = c(22.25, 
    22.38, 22.53, 22.56), SiblingNegotiation = c(4L, 0L, 2L, 
    2L), BroodSize = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), NegPerChick = c(0.8, 
    0, 0.4, 0.4)), .Names = c("Nest", "FoodTreatment", "SexParent", 
"ArrivalTime", "SiblingNegotiation", "BroodSize", "NegPerChick"
), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

The two nights differed as to the feeding regime (satiated or deprived) and are indicated in the Foodregime variable. The task is to use *ifelse* and *past* functions that make a new categorical variable that defines observations from a single night at a particular nest.

In the solutions the following code is suggested:

```
Owls <- read.table(file = "Owls.txt", header = TRUE, dec = ".")
ifelse(Owls$FoodTreatment == "Satiated", Owls$NestNight <- paste(Owls$Nest, "1",sep = "_"), Owls$NestNight <- paste(Owls$Nest, "2",sep = "_"))
```

and apparently it creates a new variable with values the endings of which vary ("-1" or "-2")

[image: Like this]

however when I call the original dataframe, all "-1" endings in the NestNight variable disappears and are turned to "-2."

[image: LIKE THIS]

Why does this happen? Did the authors miss something from the code or it's me who is not getting it?

Many thanks

EDIT: Sorry, I wanted to give a reproducible example by copying my data using *dput* but it did not work. If you can let me know how I can correct it so that it appears properly, I'd be grateful too!

Comment: R.S. Thank you very much for correcting my code. Can you please tell me how you inserted them into a table?

Comment: There is a toolbar in the edit box. Otherwise , we need to look up formatting options from the help page.

Comment: BTW, I'd like to share something about `ifelse`. It returns an object of same 'shape' as the conditional statement. So `ifelse( length(myvector)>3, myvector[3:length(myvector)], myvector[1:3] )` will not return a vector, but only the first element of that vector, as `length()` will yield only one element

Comment: I found the toolbar and read this> http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help but am still unsure. Is that the blockquote or code smape button?

Comment: The {} . Keyboard short cut is Ctrl+K I think . BTW, you can also specify    language `<!-- language: lang-r --> `

Comment: Zuur has authored some great books, but if this one really suggests this solution it demonstrates a serious lack of understanding by the author. Can you confirm that this code is suggested in the book and has not been corrected in an erratum?

Comment: To be faire, the book does not contain any solutions. They are available at this website: http://www.highstat.com/Book3/SolutionExercisesZuurIenoMeesters.R
It's in Section 6.6. Exercise 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

If you do the assignment outside the `ifelse` structure, it works:

```
Owls$NestNight <- ifelse(Owls$FoodTreatment == "Satiated", 
                         paste(Owls$Nest, "1",sep = ""),
                         paste(Owls$Nest, "2",sep = ""))
```

**Explanation**

What happens in your case is simply if you would execute the following two lines:

```
Owls$NestNight <- paste(Owls$Nest, "1",sep = "")
Owls$NestNight <- paste(Owls$Nest, "2",sep = "")
```

You first assign `paste(Owls$Nest, "1",sep = "")` to `Owls$NestNight` and then you reassign `paste(Owls$Nest, "2",sep = "")` to it. The `ifelse` is not affected by this, but you don't assign it's result to any variable.
Maybe it is more clear if you test this simple code:

```
c(a <- 1:5, a <- 6:10) #c is your ifelse, a is your Owls$NestNight
a #[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: I see, thank you so much for the clarification, and also for suggesting a soultion. I was really disturbed, but it makes sense now!